# Import modules that "overload" one another, but keep namespaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I have two modules written by another developer: `module` and `module_overload`. The module `module_overload` replaces a subset of `module`. The developer's recommended way to import these is to use:

```
from module import *
from module_overload import *
```

But I want to keep the namespaces. If I do...

```
import module
import module_overload as module
```

...the full set of `module` is lost and only the replacement subset from `module_overload` is available.

How do I perform this import, but keep namespaces?

Comment: You shouldnt try to keep the it all in the same namespace. Use `import module_overload as mo` or something similar and prefix all the updated functions accordingly. Otherwise you are losing something explicit about your code and may have problems later if for example a function name changes in `module_overload`, your code will fall back to the one in the original module and you'll be none the wiser till you get the bug report.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I'm going to use this method.

Comment: There are probably a few reasonable solutions. As a long term solution importing both modules in applications would seem to be a bad idea. I don't know whether the second overload module provides an alternative or replaces the functionality from the original module? One way perhaps would be to have the overload module internally import the original and patch it with the newer functions. Then you only ever need to import one module, depending on your needs.

Comment: `module_overload` imports `module`. Then, for classes that it overloads, it creates a new class that inherits `module`: `class Class(module.Class)`. It also adds new classes and functions not in `module`. So, to reiterate, you're suggesting I only import `module_overload`, then access non-overloaded classes from `module` with `module_overload.module`? This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I dont really know much about python modules, but it seems to me you'd want both modules to present as similar interface as possible. So the `module_overload.module` option might not be good. I was more thinking that `module_overload` would just forward on any functions that it did not overload. I presume that you don't need both functions of the same name from both modules in any one given file? It difficult to formulate a good plan in a few comments. Perhaps my initial suggestion is good in the short term, but you might want to discuss a longer term solution with your colleagues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand which developer ever thought this was a good idea, but modules are objects and you can update their `__dict__`'s using `update`:

You first import `module_overload`:

```
import module_overload
import module as temp
module_overload.__dict__.update(temp.__dict__)
module = module_overload
```

would be roughly the way to do it.

Gross.